# Interface OnClickListener cannot use my onClick Method?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-layout

here is my big problem:

http://www.bilder-space.de/show_img.php?img=7371f3-1333218887.jpg&size=original

and the code:

```
package org.madmax.sudoku;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;

public class SudokuActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        //Set up Click Listener for all Buttons
        View continueButton = findViewById(R.id.continue_button);
        continueButton.setOnClickListener(this);
        View newButton = findViewById(R.id.new_button);
        newButton.setOnClickListener(this);

        public void onClick(View v) {
            switch(v.getId()) {
            case R.id.about_button:
                Intent i = new Intent(this, About.class);
                startActivity(i);
                break;
            }
        }

    }
}
```

The error is:

```
-void is an invalid type for the variable onCLick()
```

Why does eclipse give me this errors?

Answer (score 3):

you can use onclick inside your onCreate method like this

```
 @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);



    Button newButton = findViewById(R.id.new_button);
    newButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            // your code here

        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to bring **onClick** out from **onCreate** method. Nested method declarations are not allowed in programming.

```
package org.madmax.sudoku;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;

public class SudokuActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        //Set up Click Listener for all Buttons
        View continueButton = findViewById(R.id.continue_button);
        continueButton.setOnClickListener(this);
        View newButton = findViewById(R.id.new_button);
        newButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch(v.getId()) {
        case R.id.about_button:
            Intent i = new Intent(this, About.class);
            startActivity(i);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't have a method inside another method in Java. Put the `onClick()`  ***after*** `onCreate()`, not ***inside*** it.

Answer (score 0):

You have defined `onClick` method inside of the `onCreate` method.